# Hardcoding Ruby Enumerable#reduce - I have two methods, but only one works. Why?

Tags: ruby, each, reduce

I'm a novice, and as an exercise, I have to hardcode a method that takes an array as an argument, and if ALL elements in that array are truthy, return true. If not, false.

```rb
def reduce_to_all_true(array)
  array.each do |index|
    if !index
      return false
    end
  return true
  end
end
```

This returns true if ANY element is true...

Meanwhile, the following:

```
def reduce_to_all_true(array)
  array.length.times { |index|
    if !array[index]
      return false
    end }
  return true
end
```

Behaves as expected. What I can't work out, is WHY? In my admittedly limited understanding, they are equivalent solutions. Can someone help me understand this? Thank you!

Comment: Your first example uses `if index` instead of `if array[index]` like the second

Comment: @rossta While it's definitely a bad idea to name elements in the each block `index`, the `index` variable refers to the elements and not the `index` itself. So other than a bad name, there's no issue with that

Comment: Good point. Misreading on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method the `return true` is inside the `#each` loop so it will check only the first element and return either true or false. In the second one it's after the loop, so it will return true only if the loop finishes completely wihtout finding any element that's false.

```
def reduce_to_all_true(array)
  array.each do |index| # each loop starts here
    if !index
      return false
    end
  return true # this will return true if the first element of array is true
  end # and ends here
end

def reduce_to_all_true(array)
  array.length.times { |index| # times loop starts here
    if !array[index]
      return false
    end } #and ends here
  return true #this will return true only if the times loop finishes
end
```

Comment: @LRB83 While it will work, it's a bad idea to use braces `{` `}` for blocks that spread on multiple lines. It's harder to read and against the style guide :)

Comment: thanks for the tip! In that case, errors amended, would you consider the .each method to be the better implementation?

Comment: @LRB83 Each is a better choice than time for what you're trying to do, but there's a lot of things to be addressed here and I think that might be too broad for a single SO question, but consider using `unless` instead of `if !`, omitting `return` on the last line and naming the variable inside the block something other than `index`